# Css and JS is not load after website is Published

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm trying to publish my website developed in ASPX .NET Framework on my server actually i've published other websites and till now all was going well till this one.. after publishing the website and creating new website in IIS when i try to navigate to the website the login page is shown well and all works fine but after i log-in all CSS and JS files are not load and in chrome console all css and js files not load are marks as the following

[image]

The site structure is the following:

[image]

And actually even in Default.aspx and Login.aspx i call css files as the following:

```
 <link href="styles/dashboard.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

But only in Login.aspx the files are load after login as said before noone of them is load

Which could be the cause of it? how could i fix it?

In console log i get error : `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

i've yet tryed to add all permission to IIS user but nothing..

PS: static content is enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved after setting all bindings to HTTPS with Let's encrypt SSL, the issue was as Jokies said that in Login the css and js was required to http as all bindings but for some reason after login the css and js was required in https.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that your website are trying to load https in http website. You could  try to enable https for your website as well or disable https for your project.

Comment: Oh you're right but actually i can't get why in login page the same css and js libs are request to http while after login the request is going to https..

Comment: @IgorMytyuk I remembered if you enabled https for an asp.net core project and host it as http then you will receive same error and symptom. It sounds like HTS has been enabled on your site.

Comment: Besides, you could get it work when you change your http binding to https right?